# difference between jQuery selectors `:` and `*[type=*]`

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm a newbie in jQuery. I want to know the difference between the following ways of selecting elements in jquery :

`$(':button')`     ,  `$('input[type="button"]'` and `$('input:button')`

And also

`$(':input')` and `$('input')`

Does the `$('input')` selector leave behind any elements, which `$(':input')` would select ?? If yes, what are they ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of :button](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) :

> An equivalent selector to $( ":button" ) using valid CSS is $(
>   "button, input[type='button']" ).

`:button` is just a jQuery shortcut letting you select both the `input` elements of type `button` and the [`button` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Using `$('input[type="button"]')`, you would miss an element defined as `<button>some content</button>`.

[`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) *"Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements"* while the `input` selector only selects `input` elements (so not the `textarea`, the `select` and the `button` elements).

Comment: please answer all the questions i've asked

Comment: please don't mind, but i feel your answer is not complete because i didn't get the difference between  `$('input')` and `$(':input')`

Comment: @AdityaVikas : the difference is there in the post right. `$('input')' selector selects only which is written with the 'input' tag `<input type="text"/>` or `<input type="button"/>` etc., i.e only the input tag. Whereas, `$(':input')` selects all tags including `select , textarea, button`